# How To Refresh Item Positions In Recylcerview for filtering?

Tags: java, android

I want to filter recyclerView items, my code is working well in terms of displaying filtered items but when I am clicking on those items it's clicking on previous items though those items are not visible. I thought the problem is on item clickListener implementation but I have tried two recylcerview onitemClickListener implementation but both of them aren't working.
Can You Please Help? Thanks In Advance.

Here is the filter code in Recyclerview Adapter.

```
 public void updateList(List<ProductInfo> list){
    mProductList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here is the Clicklistener on Recyclerview in Activity.

```
mProductAdapter = new AdapterTest(mProductInfos, new AdapterTest.ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPositionClicked(View v, int position) {
            ProductInfo productInfo = mProductInfos.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(VegetableActivity.this, DescriptionActvity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_OBJECT, productInfo);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClicked(View v, int position) {

        }
    });
```

And This is the Adapter Class.

```
public class AdapterTest extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTest.MyviewHolder> {

private List<ProductInfo> mProductList;
private ClickListener listener;

public class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

    private TextView mProductName, mProductPrice, mProductRating;
    private ImageView mProductImage;
    private WeakReference<ClickListener> listenerRef;

    public MyviewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        listenerRef = new WeakReference<>(listener);

        mProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        mProductPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        //mProductRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_rating);
        mProductImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // if(view.getId() == decreaseView.getId()){
        //  Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // }else {
        //   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "ROW PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  }
        listenerRef.get().onPositionClicked(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        return false;
    }
}

public AdapterTest(List<ProductInfo> productList, ClickListener listener){
    mProductList = productList;
    this.listener = listener;

}

@Override
public MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.vegetable_layout, parent, false);

    return new MyviewHolder(itemView, listener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyviewHolder holder, int position) {

    ProductInfo productInfo = mProductList.get(position);
    holder.mProductName.setText(productInfo.getProductName());
    holder.mProductPrice.setText(productInfo.getProductPrice());
    //holder.mProductRating.setText(productInfo.getProductRating());


    Picasso.get()
            .load(productInfo.getProductImage())
            .into(holder.mProductImage);

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mProductList.size();
}

public interface ClickListener {

    void onPositionClicked(View v, int position);

    void onLongClicked(View v, int position);
}


public void updateList(List<ProductInfo> list){
    mProductList = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can move below code segement to onCLick evenet of the recycle item

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(VegetableActivity.this, DescriptionActvity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_OBJECT, productInfo);
            startActivity(intent);
```

you donot need the onPositionClicked listener for that and you can remove `ProductInfo productInfo = mProductInfos.get(position);` as well. I have no clear idea about what u doing. but let say u want to nevigate to another page when u click on recycle item. u can add it like below

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyviewHolder holder, int position) {

        ProductInfo productInfo = mProductList.get(position);
        holder.mProductName.setText(productInfo.getProductName());
        holder.mProductPrice.setText(productInfo.getProductPrice());
        //holder.mProductRating.setText(productInfo.getProductRating());


        Picasso.get()
                .load(productInfo.getProductImage())
                .into(holder.mProductImage);

//new code - start here
holder.anyuielementInItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        { 
            // Do things you want
        } 
    }); 

//

    }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much . That helps a lot. Though i need     ProductInfo productInfo = mProductInfos.get(position); this line of code cause I am passing the object to DescriptionActivity activity.

Comment: @subhasarkar nice to hear it. Happy coding :)